# Fix the upstream dependency conflict tfjs-react-native

Tags: react-native, npm, expo

I'm trying to install tfjs-react-native for a project that it's also using expo-camera but I get an error.
I followed the instructions on https://www.npmjs.com/package/@tensorflow/tfjs-react-native and installed every dependency, but I fail at the last step which is:

> npm install @tensorflow/tfjs-react-native

I'm not able to understand what it's asking me. It seems that tfjs-react-native tries to use expo-camera@7 and I have installed the last one which is 12.3.0. Is that the problem? If so how can I fix this?

Hopefully somebody can help me out. Thanks

> While resolving: alpr@1.0.0 npm ERR! Found: expo-camera@12.3.0 npm
> ERR! node_modules/expo-camera npm ERR!   expo-camera@"~12.3.0" from
> the root project npm ERR!  npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency: npm
> ERR! peer expo-camera@"^7.0.0" from
> @tensorflow/tfjs-react-native@0.8.0 npm ERR!
> node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-react-native npm ERR!
> @tensorflow/tfjs-react-native@"^0.8.0" from the root project npm ERR!
> npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry npm ERR! this
> command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps npm ERR! to accept an
> incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.

Answer (score 2):

I solved it using `--legacy-peer-deps`. Now I was able to install it, my project still don't work but I will post the problem in another question.